# Change table variable to temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a certain stored procedure written years ago. It uses a table variable. Inside the code it's doing:

```
declare @OpportunityVS3 as SF_OpportunityMerge
insert @TableVariable select * from /*...*/
```

This is inside a job that runs every five minutes. There used to be no issues in the past because the `select` used to collect around 10 to 1000 records… But now sometimes the select is trying to insert a million records.

Given this issue, I think I am forced to change the `@TableVariable` to a `#TempTable`. What do you think? Do I have any other option?

At the end of the SP, it’s passing the Variable to another SP:

```
exec [dbo].[SF_MergeOpportunity] @OpportunityVS3, @LastUpdateDate
```

I guess I will have to write it all in the same stored procedure, because temporary tables cannot be passed, right?

Below is the definition of the `@TableVariable` that is being used and the code I would have to change:

```
declare @OpportunityVS3 as SF_OpportunityMerge

insert  @OpportunityVS3 select Opportunity_id, Salesforce_id, AccountId, Age__c,  
-- (continues)

merge [BU2].[dbo].[Salesforce_Opportunity] as TARGET 
using ( select  Opportunity_id, 
    Salesforce_id, 
    AccountId, 
    Age__c, 
    Amount, 
    Bill99Amount__c, 
    BJ_Marketing__c
    -- (continues)
    from @OpportunityVS3 ) as SOURCE on (TARGET.Opportunity_id = SOURCE.Opportunity_id) 

exec [dbo].[SF_MergeOpportunity] @OpportunityVS3, @LastUpdateDate
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: What's the definition of the table variable? Probably you just need to add an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try without changing the way you work:

- Force the compiler to take cardinalities of `TABLE` variables into account by specifying `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` in queries using the `TABLE` variables
- Supply a suitable `UNIQUE INDEX` or `PRIMARY KEY` for the `TABLE` variable

A downside of `TABLE` variables is that there are no statistics associated with them. The SQL compiler will produce better execution plans when it can take statistics into account. Therefore you can improve performance considerably when you switch to temporary tables because these **do** have statistics.

When you switch to temporary tables, you would no longer pass a `TABLE` variable to your stored procedure anymore. Your stored procedure would then be written using a temporary table that it knows exists beforehand - ie was created before the stored procedure is executed.

You would write your stored procedure as though the temporary table were an ordinary table. When you write the stored procedure using a temporary table, SQL Server management studio will underline certain parts in red so it appears as though there are errors in your stored procedure. But if the syntax is correct, creating/altering the stored procedure will work just fine.

Read this [excellent essay](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16386/65699) on the differences between `TABLE` variables and temporary tables, to see how usage may impact performance. Especially topics **No column statistics** and **Indexes**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; after much testing I found that 'inserting to the table variable is not the issue'.
Basically the SP is doing:

insert @TableVariable
select * from [linkedserver].[dbo].[remote_table]

merge [LocalTable] as target 
using (select * from @TableVariable)

The 'execution plan'  identifies the insert as 98% of the cost of the batch, but it only takes 2 minutes, and the insert is what its taking most time (more than 30 minutes).

Why the person that wrote the code, didnt do??
merge [LocalTable] as target 
using (select * from [linkedserver].[dbo].[remote_table])

Comment: @Chicago1988 To be able to help you better, it is important to include all relevant information inside the question (see about posting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). I'm speaking of table definitions including all indexes defined on the tables involved in all queries in the stored procedures, all relevant stored procedures, the execution plan for the 'slow queries' and so on. Without seeing the full detail all people can do is give generic advice and indications, like what I did in my answer.

Comment: @Chicago1988 Anyway, I answered this question as best I could. Changing the question to be as detailed as requested would change the nature of the question: not about using temporary tables instead of table variables, but about optimizing your stored procedures. I suggest if you want to supply more details, make a new question about optimizing your situation. Close *this* question with a ✔ if you find the information I gave you useful.